# What is the best way to compare images with text?

Tags: image, algorithm, opencv, comparison

I have two images mostly filled with text, what is the best way to determine whether these two images are similar or different. Assume they use same font, font sizes etc. One of the two images might have been corrupted a bit (e.g. lost few characters, or a letter 'O' was chopped off and now looks like 'C' etc).

What is the best way to accomplish this, I am bit familiar with OpenCV, I can implement suggested algorithms using that.

Thank you very much

MB

Comment: Perceptual diffs? There are tools out there which can compare two images pixel-by-pixel and will output a new image showing their differences.

Comment: EMS - Hiring PhD student is ruled out :), I thought these problems have already established solutions in open world (opensource).
Anthony - Thank you will look into these tools.

Comment: @EMS LOL!!!


Normally this forum posts should exhibit some sort of individual research into the problem. Have a look at patter recognition, for example. A friend of mine also did something to do colour pattern recognition after having converted to HSV rather than RGB, but I know no details of that.

Comment: I should admit this is very open ended question and I am not an expert in this area, so is trying to reach out for suggestions. I did try some generic image comparison algorithms like SSIM Index etc, they are not helping me that much. I thought about OCR solution using tesseract-ocr, but felt I am trying to invent something which has already been solved. My intuition is many search engines and scanning software (which converts bills to text etc) solved this problem, so there must have been successful research and papers about this problem.

Comment: @EMS sorry only LOL was regarding your comment, rest was about the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tesseract-ocr. We can install the same and extract the test in python. Read the below link
https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-extract-text-from-images-using-tesseract-ocr-engine-and-python-22934125fdd5

What is challenging here is to remove name date etc from the text.